# VBScript - Alternative to SendKeys

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys

I have noticed that SendKeys inside a VBScript does not work when the user is not logged in or the script is being executed as LOCAL SYSTEM.

Example:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "telnet 192.168.1.50"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "some telnet command"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "another telnet command"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Is there any other way to send keys to an application? SendInput does not seem to work in a .vbs file...

Comment: You can run the command directly. https://www.google.com/search?q=vbscript+run+command

Comment: Thanks, but this is unfortunately not possible, since I want to execute a telnet command. I have updated the example above to show what I really want to do.

Comment: I think telnet can take a script file?

Comment: Sendkeys is a very wrong way to do this.

Comment: I know, that's why we want to change this... 
Sorry for asking, but can you please show me an example how to start telnet with a script file? I haven't found any possibility to do so...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzzwsz3t(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: Use a `telnet` that's actually scriptable (e.g. [`plink`](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) from the [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) suite). *Never* use `SendKeys` for this kind of automation.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at it. Is there any possiblity to achieve the same without using third party utilities?

Comment: Aside from the approach you already tried (and which I would strongly discourage) I'm not aware of any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your constraints, this is what I would do:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd"
WScript.Sleep 100 
WshShell.AppActivate "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" 
WScript.Sleep 100 
WshShell.SendKeys "telnet 192.168.1.50"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "some telnet command"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "another telnet command"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```